# Rotating a fire / exhaust animated sprite around a 2D spaceship whilst still keeping it at the bottom C++

Tags: c++, rotation, 2d

In the below code I have the player ship face in the direction of the mouse position.
How exactly would I go about attaching an exhaust / fire animation to the bottom of the ship so that it always stays at the bottom of the ship and rotates with the ship? 
The origin x, y points of all sprites are centered, which cannot be changed in the game engine I'm using.

```
player_rotation = atan2(y - player.GetY(), x - player.GetX()) * (180/3.14159);
if (player_rotation < 0) player_rotation = 360 - (-player_rotation);
```

Angle 0 / 360 is when the ship is facing right. 90 is facing up. So it's clockwise starting from the right direction.

Comment: I noticed a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1581778/10077) that might be helpful.

Comment: Place the fire animation at a -ve offset from the origin of the sprite. And then when you manipulate the ship sprite, apply the same manipulation to the fire animation.

Comment: What do you mean by ve offset exactly?